# jekyll --watch not regenerating in specific repo

Tags: ruby, git, jekyll, watch

collaborating on a github project at work. when i run `jekyll serve --watch`, it doesn't regenerate after code changes. however, i switched over to my personal site (also running on jekyll) just to check, and that recognizes changes just fine.

versions:

- jekyll 2.4.0
- ruby 2.0.0

gem list: https://gist.github.com/ryantroyford/4b749ce30bdfcb82b874

i've used the `jekyll serve --force_polling` approach, which works. i would just rather pinpoint the real issue, and not have to do that every time.

here is the output for my personal site, after firing up jekyll and making a few superficial changes:
[image: my-site]

and here is the output from the project i've been working on, after doing the same. several changes have been made to the code while jekyll has been running:
[image: foundations]

no idea what to make of it. is there some bug in the collaborative repo throwing a wrench into everything? thanks in advance for your help - this one has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

In the _config.yml file of your personal site, you have some old keys that are no longer used.

Look for **auto**, **watch** and **serve** and remove them to make the deprecation message disappear.